# Flatness of $R/(x)$ with $R$ being local

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, flatness, local-rings

> Let $R$ be a commutative local ring and let $x \in R$ be a non-unit. Suppose that for all exact sequences  $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ the following sequence is also exact $0 \rightarrow A/xA \rightarrow B/xB \rightarrow C/xC \rightarrow 0$. Prove or disprove $x=0$.

All I found out is that $0 \rightarrow A/xA \rightarrow B/xB \rightarrow C/xC \rightarrow 0$ is the same as $0 \rightarrow A \otimes R/(x) \rightarrow B \otimes R/(x) \rightarrow C \otimes R/(x) \rightarrow 0$. So if $R/(x)$ would be flat for all $x$ not a unit then the statement is false.

In general $R/(x)$ is not a flat $R$-module. For example choose $R=\mathbb{Z}$ then $ \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$  is not a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module. I haven't found any example for this where $R$ is a local ring.

Can anyone help me out here how this is done?

Comment: If R/xR is flat, then it is projective, because it is finitely generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $(R,m)$ be a local ring and $x\in m$ such that $R/(x)$ is $R$-flat. Then $x=0$.

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183406/121097) we get $(x)=(x^2)$, so $x=ax^2$ for some $a\in R$. Then $x(1-ax)=0$ and since $1-ax\notin m$ we get $x=0$.

Comment: Okay that helps. It's now clear to me where the local property is needed: Since $x$ is in $m=$Jacobsen-radical $(1-ax)$ is a unit and therfore $x=0$

Comment: We can even conclude: Let $R$ be an arbitrary ring and $x\in$ Jacobsen radical such that $R/(x)$ is $R$-flat. Then $x=0$

Comment: I am still a little confused. No matter if $(x)=(x^2)$ or not $x \in M_{tor}(R/(x))$ so as MooS has pointed out $R/(x)$ is never flat. no local property is needed. Moreover for any ideal $I$ the $R$-modul $R/I$ cannot be flat for the same reason: $I \in M_{tor}(R/I)$. Is this correct?

Comment: The reason is why I am not happy yet is, that I don't know what happens  with the tor module if $x$ is a zero diviser.

Comment: @CookieMaster I don't understand your notation $M_{tor}$, and Moos answer is obviously wrong: $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ is $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$-flat since it is projective.

Comment: $M_{tor}$ is the torsion module

Comment: I guess for MooS answer to work $R$ must be integral domain.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Take $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(3)}$, the localization of $\Bbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(3)$, and $x=3$.
Let $$0 \to R \to R \to R/3R \to 0$$ be exact, where the second arrow is $x \mapsto 3x$, the third arrow is projection.

Tensoring with $R/3R$ we get
$$0 \to R/3R \to R/3R \to R/3R \otimes_R R/3R \to 0$$
which is not exact since the second arrow is the zero map (not injective).

Comment: thanks this is a great example

Answer (score 1):

Flat implies torsion-free. In particular $R/xR$ is never flat when $x \neq 0$.

Yes, the problem is that $R/xR$ is indeed torsion-free if $x$ is a zero divisor. So the right solution should be the following:

Flat + finitely presented implies projective.
In the local case projective and free are the same notions.

We deduce: If $R$ is local, then flatness of $R/xR$ implies that it is even free. Since it is generated by one element, we would have $R/xR \cong R$, which is wrong for $x \neq 0$, since $x$ annihilates a generator of $R/xR$ but does not annihilate any generator of $R$.

Comment: And why does it?

Comment: Flat implies torsion-free. I have prooven this already. No need to do this again for me. So  $x \in M_{Tor}(R/xR)$. So this answers my overall question with yes $x$ must be zero right?

Comment: This would mean that R doesn`t need to be local, wouldn't it?

Comment: Z/3Z is Z/6Z-flat since it is projective.